# How do I add a custom div with a class to CKEditor?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I have ckeditor installed via the WYSIWYG module. I need to select a group of paragraphs and give surround them with a div that has a class and end up with this

```
<div class="my_class">
<p>test text 1</p>
<p>test text 2</p>
<p>test text 3</p>
<p>test text 4</p>
</div>
```

this div could also surround other elements like links, lists, etc. I have no problem adding custom styles but can't quite add any custom formats.

Answer (score 0):

This module is maybe what you're looking for

https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_div_manager